# How to split based on patient folders for cross validation?

Tags: python, cross-validation

I need to split my images into test and train sets in cross-validation so that images of each patient can be either in train or test. Each patient has a different number of images.

```
class 1:
      patient_1:
         a.png
         b.png
         c.png
      patient_2:
         a.png
class 2:
      patient_n:
         e.png
      patient_n+1:
         f.png
         g.png
```

Comment: You need to give 70% for the training , 10% for the test and 20% for the validation

Comment: @abdou_dev Ok but I can't use the built-in CV because the same patient should be in one set